# Is my Arduino security scheme good?

Tags: security, encryption, arduino

I am working on a project where an Arduino will send measurements and receive commands through an Ethernet interface and a REST API to open and lock a door. For all means, we can consider that the devices are protected, but that the Ethernet network may be accessed. Therefore, a Man-in-the-middle attack is plausible.

The commands to open/lock the door will be part of the reply of an HTTP GET request. In order to prevent a MITM attack where the response is faked to open the lock, I want to use some kind of encrypted response. Now, Arduinos lack the power to use HTTPS, and I want it to be Arduinos because of costs and ease of development.

I have come up with the following scheme:

- Both the Arduino and the server have an identical set of index-value registers. The value will be used as a code to encrypt using AES-128.
- When the Arduino sends its GET request, it also sends a randomly selected index, indicating to the server which value to use to encrypt the open/lock command.
- The server sends a clear text response (JSON) where the command field is an encrypted text.
- The Arduino will decode it and apply the required action.

The Arduino will also send some sensor data from time to time. In this case, it will send the index of the code it used to encrypt the data and the encrypted data.

The set of index-value keys is large, so repetitions are rare (but may occur from time to time).

My question is, is this scheme secure? Am I missing something? Is there any other more tested alternative for securing these interactions that doesn't involve using a more advanced platform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scheme you have detailed is no more secure than just using the same key for AES the whole time, you might as well do that.  Everything else is unnecessary.

Comment: I see, so there is no possibility that someone with enough time and computing power can somehow guess the key?

Comment: Provided you have properly randomly generated it, they'd have to try every single key.  Which won't happen before the heat death of the universe...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the response

Comment: Just keep in mind that both your server and client have a copy of the same key.  So if either accidentally expose that key, everything falls apart.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about a concrete software development problem. It should be asked in another StackExchange site like Arduino or Security.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the answers. deeply sorry for bothering with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ESP2866 based Arduino. It does not cost significantly more, it uses the same tools but you can use SSL instead of rolling your own solution. I have used the Wemos D1 boards and they work as a drop in Arduino replacement.

Comment: I considered it, but I'm seeking specifically for a wired solution. I keep it in my toolbox for future use :)